# Flutter: Realtime API data fetch

Tags: api, flutter, stream, real-time

I came across to this one solution where we need to use Timer() in order to fetch the changes over time and add to stream controller. Just a simple question, does this method will consume more internet usage for the user?

Because, even the API data does not have new value, the apps still will fetch the API when the period in Timer() reach, which I consider this is just waste of process and internet usage.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the use of a stream in your post, hence if your API implements a stream too, you do not need to use a Timer() to make requests (also known as Polling).

You just need to subscribe to your API stream to receive updated data.